# .data() fails to update code showed in the Chrome inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm making a call to my server to rename a specific file, here is the code client side:

```
function rename_file(filepath, filename, object){
    $("#loading").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');
    $.getJSON('queries.php', { 
        q: 'renameFile', 
        old_path: filepath, 
        new_name: filename
    }, function(data){
        if (data.message == "File renamed") {
            $("#loading").html(data.message);
            console.log(data.name);
            var mod_name = data.name;
            object.data('file', mod_name);
            console.log(object.data('file'));
        } else {
            $("#loading").html(data.message);
        }
    });
}
```

The function is called like that:

```
rename_file(old_filepath, new_filename, $(this));
```

Where `$(this)` is :

```
<div class="filename_container" id="file_165161" data-file="toto.doc" data-folder="" class="fileClic">
    toto.doc
</div>
```

When I log in console what I get when I rename `toto.doc` into `toto2016.doc` is:

```
toto2016.doc
toto2016.doc
```

So the data contained in `data-file` should be `toto2016.doc`, but when I inspect in Chrome inspector I still get `toto.doc`. Because of that if I rename the file twice, it fails.

I have tested that the right object gets transmitted to the function, and it is. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. When you set a value using `data()` it only updates the object which jQuery keeps in memory - it does not update any attribute of the element in the DOM.

If you retrieve the value using the getter of `data()` you will see that the value has been set correctly.

Comment: thanks, the getter indeed give the right info. Is it a bug or it's made on purpose ?

Comment: It's entirely on purpose. Using an in-memory object means better performance than having to read/write to the DOM for every request and also means that any datatype can be stored, not just a string. For example, you can store a selector, a Date or even a jQuery object in `data()` if you needed to.

Comment: oh very interesting that you can store an object! Thanks for the explanation. I'll mark it as solved as soon as timer allow me to do so. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can substitute `.attr()` for `.data()` to adjust `html`

Comment: @guest271314 entirely possible, but if you're doing it correctly you should never have to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not certain follow "doing it correctly" ? Not updating `DOM` element attribute ? Or using `.data()` differently ?

Comment: I mean that you shouldn't need to update the DOM when using `data()`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah, OP should not be concerned with a specific attribute value visually appearing in `DOM` where value set at `.data()` is actually accessible ?

Comment: That's it exactly. You can rely on `data()` being set in jQuery's internal cache, so as long as you always retrieve it through `data()` as well you shouldn't have any issues.